# Why error: ‘locate_zone’ is not a member of ‘std::chrono’

Tags: c++, c++11

Code:

```
//test.cpp
#include<chrono>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  string str("Europe/Oslo");
  std::chrono::locate_zone(str);
}
```

Compile:

```
/tools/gcc/6.3.0/bin/g++ --std=c++11 test.cpp
```

Output:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
```

test.cpp:6:3: error: ‘locate_zone’ is not a member of ‘std::chrono’
   std::chrono::locate_zone(str);
   ^~~

Comment: Because time zone support arrives in c++20. Always check [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) first.

Comment: As LogicStuff said, `tzdb` comes with C++20. [Here you can see](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/tzdb/current_zone) the `(since C++20)` text.

Answer (score 3):

You can experiment with this C++20 feature today by using [Howard Hinnant's free, open source, time zone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html).

You'll need to change the namespace from `std::chrono` to `date`:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include<chrono>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  string str("Europe/Oslo");
  date::locate_zone(str);
}
```

[Some installation required.](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation)

[Help is available.](https://gitter.im/HowardHinnant/date?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge)